# global variables in multiple files return undefined

Tags: javascript, html

I have two javascripts in first I'm declaring array and in second I want approach to this array but the returning of this function is undefined.

first javascript

```
    var starts=[];

    function blabla(){
        for(i=0;i<10;i++){
            starts[0].push(0);
        }
    }
```

second javascript

```
function blabla1(){
   alert(starts[0]);
}
```

Do you have some instruction how to fix it ?

Answer (score 3):

You are calling .push on the first element of the array instead of on the array.

So inside of the for loop I would use

```
starts.push
```

Instead of

```
starts[0].push
```

Answer (score 0):

I think calling function will solve your problem. If not please put it on codepen and share

first javascript

```
var starts=[];
  function blabla(){
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
      starts.push(0);
    }
  }
blabla();
```

second javascript

```
function blabla1(){
  alert(starts[0]);
}
blabla1();
```

Answer (score 0):

That's probably happening because your defining the variable and trying to access it from different [scopes](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp). One way is to use the window object:

```
window.starts=[];

function blabla(){
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        starts.push(0); //starts[0].push(0) seems wrong without more code
    }
}
```

and then:

```
function blabla1(){
   alert(window.starts[0]);
}
```